# Checking constructor/method parameters

Tags: java, guava

I'm usually checking almost all constructor and public method parameters via Guava's Precondition methods. Private method parameters usually with assertions. However, now I'm thinking about replacing "internal" Precondition checks, that is checks in constructors/factory methods/general methods (which are not part of the public API/the application API)... with assertions, what do you think? Maybe it's a bit faster this way, because I've a lot of checks ;-)

Edit:
I mean also public constructors and factories which *shouldn't* be part of the public API, just used internally, for instance:

```
/**
 * Constructor with both, complete and modifying page.
 * 
 * @param complete
 *          to be used as a base for this container
 * @param modifying
 *          to be used as a base for this container
 */
public NodePageContainer(final @Nonnull NodePage complete,
    final @Nonnull NodePage modifying) {
  assert complete != null;
  assert modifying != null;
  mComplete = complete;
  mModified = modifying;
}
```

Before I've had `mComplete = checkNotNull(complete);`... but it's only called from a class in another package and shouldn't even be part of the public API. Would be great if Java would allow to reduce the visibility of such classes ;-)

Comment: You use @Nonnull annotation, assert and preconditions to check null objects... In an ideal world, is it possible to use only annotation, with some sort of aop check ?

Comment: @Istao it is, of course, with AspectJ.

Answer (score 7):

Assertions and preconditions are not the same thing.

Assertions check that invariants are respected: it checks that **your** own algorithm work as expected. For example, that the numbers produced by your random generator are always positive. They can be deactivated once you have checked that everything worked fine and that you had no assertion failures.

Guava preconditions check that the **caller** does not pass invalid arguments or do not call methods that shouldn't be called. For example, that the limit passed as argument to the `nextInt()` method is bigger than 0, or that `setSeed()` is not called after the random generator has started.

If your goal is to enforce that the caller of your API respects its contract, I would thus use Guava preconditions, and not assertions.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely what I mean. Internally in constructors (or even package private constructors) which should never be used from the public for instance or even method parameters I've used preconditions. But I'm always enabling assertions such that it should be reasonable to check with assertions and only check the public API methods with preconditions.

Answer (score 3):

According to `Effective Java` you should use checks (`Preconditions`) for API exposed method and assertions for non-API methods. This means that any method / constructor that is not `private` or `package private` should use checks. WRT, `private` and `package private`, it is more efficient to use assertions with the suggestion of enabling the assertions early in deployment to assist in debugging, and then choose to disable them later in the production cycle as confidence grows and performance becomes as issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks (but even though most public constructors shouldn't be part of the public API). BTW: I sometimes or even often struggle with the class/method visibility "modifiers" (don't know if it's the right name -- private/package private/protected and public). For instance sometimes I have to invoke either a public (static) factory method or a public constructor just because it isn't possible to reduce the visibility and thus it's even part of the public API whereas it shouldn't. That's one thing I really like in Scala (which has fine grained visibility modifiers...).

Comment: Generally this kind of thing is addressed by having two projects. One would contain the public API (probably just interfaces) and the other would contain the implementation.

Comment: I didn't even think about this, hmmm :-) But I think it would introduce a cyclic dependency: For instance an Axis interface and Axis-implementations (for instance XPath axis to iterate over a tree-structure). The axis are both exposed and used internally for instance to delete a whole subtree when a user calls remove() on a transaction cursor. Thus, the axis implementations should be part of the public API but are also used in the "core" project. But after a second thought only the core will depend on the API-project (in my case maven module). Wow, great idea :-)

Comment: But the user would have to include both the API- and the core-modules and still has access to the public methods which shouldn't be exposed? Otherwise I would introduce a cyclic dependency as the core-project also uses the public API. Or no, it's just necessary to include the core-project which depends on the API, but then again I wouldn't benefit from changing from a package with a public API to an api-project

Comment: I would post that as a question. I would be interested to know suggestions. The one advantage to the two systems if using maven is that you could import the API with compile scope and the implementation with runtime scope.

Comment: I guess this is why so many projects have "internal" package structures with public classes you can get but are not supposed to. Please comment back if you get a good suggestion.

Comment: Hm, best way seems to document that a class is for internal use or part of the public API. But hmm well...

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your reasoning, but I'd use `Precondition` in your example. The constructor is visible from the outside, so you can bet somebody will call it someday. And the test is so cheap, so it's not worth the trouble.

Actually, that's my auxiliary criterion: I mostly decide according to the API / non-API principle, but sometimes make an exception for very cheap or very expensive checks (also depending on the context and the amount of possible harm due to missing check).

Comment: Actually noone ever should call this class except from my core-project. I currently want to introduce an API maven module (proposed by John B in the comments). However, hm, I think this doesn't solve the problem as the user still must include the dependency to the api- _and_ the core-project (and has access to the public constructors...). Or I would have a cyclic redundancy (api-project depends on core-project and vice versa -- or I actually didn't understand it correctly.

Comment: the cyclic redundancy would occur because I use the public API sometimes also internally

Comment: @Johannes  I don't like the two projects idea at all - it may work but it's just a complicated workaround for missing C++ `friend`s. You could duplicate the API part used in the core project and so avoid the cyclic dependency. But for me such an duplication sounds terrible. Maybe you could use three projects: 1. the common part, on which everything depends, 2. the core library, 3. the nowhere else used API. I'm not sure if I mean it seriously.. it started like this but sounds too crazy. *I'd suggest to post a separate question concerning the project split.*

Comment: I did... hm but no real "easy and workable" suggestions except writing proper Javadoc comments.